How to find netbooted system boot log when login fails?
I tried to netboot an ubuntu using pxe, dhcp and tftp. as a summary, I copied all the / to /nfsroot/ and then configured the server dhcp and tftp. Now, the client can obtain IP (so dhcp seems to work properly) and tftp boots linux from server's /nfsroot. but in the boot process I can see some failures but as they go very fast! I can't read the messages. the system reaches the login (GUI login fails and tty1 login is showed) but the user/pass returns wrong login. I wanted to find the failed processes which must be the reason of login fail but nothing is written in /nfsroot/var/log
As I cannot login to the client system (even no ssh connections is accepted), no commands can be executed. I can access the /nfsroot filesystem from server. what should I do?
UPDATE:
I guess that the main problem is that the file system is not mounted correctly (nfs root, proc, sys, ...). I've checked /etc/exports and /etc/fstab but they seem to be correct. with no error/failure message, I cant find the problem. FYI, my /etc/exports is like this:
/nfsroot     192.168.2.0/24 (rw,no_root_squash,async,insecure,no_subtree_check

and /etc/fstab as follows:
192.168.2.50:/nfsroot    /   nfs  auto,rw,nouser,exec,nolock,async,nofail,noatime,_netdev,ac,bg 0 0
none    /tmp      tmpfs   defaults   0 0 
tempfs  /dev/shm  tmpfs   defaults   0 0 
sysfs   /sys      sysfs   defaults   0 0
proc    /proc     proc    defaults   0 0


"copied all the / to /nfsroot/"? Does the hardware match?

This question is similar to: How can current Ubuntu versions be installed via PXE network boot and an automated installation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@waltinator: this post is not about linux installation over pxe but it is about booting linux over nfs. I think the title and body of the question is clear about this differencce, isn't it?

this is a beuwolf cluster for hpc system which many pcs boot on network from server's HDD. their hardware are not exactly similar but previously, we had only some minor and acceptable problems with different hardware differences
